# Compare csv file data & dataset

Tags: sql, database, performance, csv, compare

I have csv file with more than one hundred thousand + records & data set with same amount of data. My csv file has first column as mobile phone I need to check if that mobile number exists in dataset / db then I need to put that records in other file. What could be the fastest way of doing this. Currently I am comparing each record which is not advisable way for such large amount of data. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Your best two options are either using bulk insert to a temp table, then querying the temp table against your dataset or using a scripting language to pull from both as arrays for a comparison:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16